# Python Pandas Dataframe vs dict vs list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary

So, I am writing a huge module wherein I am calling 10 other modules. These "10 other modules" store ref data as list of list.

For example I have a module refdataCollection.py that has this data, none of which are over a 100 items in each.

```
allFees = [['FeeID','RegFees',''HXVFees'],
['ABC',34,21],
['ABV',31,23],
['PGC',33,25],]

allCust = [['CustID','CustCode',''CustName'],
['1','ARN','Company 1'],
['2','BRS','Company 2'],
['3','AJN','Company 3'],]
```

Thru the course of my main module I call in on these modules like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import refdataCollection as refdata

def getRefData(refDataName):
    return getattr(refdata,refDataName)

def getRefDataDataFrame(refDataName):
    records = getRefData(refDataName)
    headers = records[0]
    refDataDF = pd.DataFrame(records[1:],columns=headers)
    return refDataDF
```

Then in the main module itself, I could be getting my values like this:

```
feesDataFrame = getRefDataDataFrame('allFees')
thisFee = feesDataFrame[ (feesDataFrame['FeeID'] == 'ABC')]
```

I could be doing this 100s of times considering I have multiple method calling multiple such ref data.

Question is:
Is using the dataframe the right way to do it? For such small sets of data, Am I better off using a list or dict instead of pandas? My approach is taking a lot of time, some a few seconds to loop thru a set of 50K records.

Comment: Do you recontruct the feesDataFrame in every iteration in your loop, potentially even reading it from disc? This could of course lead to slow performance. I'd rather make the dataframes available once (hence they are in memory) or store the data in a database. On a nother note, the question seems really broad since a huge chunk of context is missing

Comment: @Quickmean2K1 - No actually... I am creating the dataframe once.... The module getRefDataDataFrame() gets called only once and is cashed before the loop.I think its the query that is killing me...  (feesDataFrame['FeeID'] == 'ABC')

Comment: how long does it take, if you only loop through 1, 10 and 100 items. Could you provide some numbers maybe using jupyters `%%timeit`magic?

Comment: @Quickmean2K1 - A loop containing 45K records, takes cumulatively about 300 seconds for just one such ref data. I have roughly around 10

Comment: how many `thisFee`lines do you have in one loop? I just tried accessing one element of a 5 million row data frame and it happened instantly (4.0 ms). Reading the data takes like 4 seconds. Could you provide the relevant code of the loop?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 - I actually changed my logic. Instead of dataframe, I moved to dictionary and hat cut my time by one third. I do see that your result may have yielded only 4ms, which might make sense. I was spending 200 seconds with more than one condition in my query clause. While it wouldn't have mattered on a smaller scale, but with 43K * 20 such methods (and some being called twice, even thrice), it added up. Converting it to dict instead of dataframe made sense. Thanks for being patient with me